# Bot framework custom state data in Azure Cosmos DB - Change db name

Tags: c#, botframework

I have implemented custom state data store with Azure Cosmos DB as instructed in here - [Manage custom state data with Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb)

It works fine. The azure extension has created a db called 'botdb' and a collection called 'botcollection' in my Cosmos DB endpoint.

Is there anyway that i can change the db name from 'botdb' to something else?

Otherwise i am able to store state data, **only for one bot** in one Cosmos DB endpoint. I am planning to store state data for multiple bots in same Cosmos DB endpoint.

Will i have to manually implement IBotDataStore?

Comment: I'm not sure about DocumentDbUri formats, can't you specify dbname inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the database name and the collection name while creating your store:

```
var store = new DocumentDbBotDataStore(uri, key, "dbname","collectionname");
```

If you look at the constructor of `DocumentDbBotDataStore`, `'botdb'` and `'botcollection'` are added as default values,

```
public DocumentDbBotDataStore(Uri serviceEndpoint, string authKey, string databaseId = "botdb", string collectionId = "botcollection");
```

That's the reason azure extension had created a db called 'botdb' and a collection called 'botcollection' in your Cosmos DB endpoint.